# Can dtype be used for assignment in order to set -99.0's for numeric and X's for text?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, dtype

I have 20+ columns of data.  There has to be a non-manual way to use data type in order to fill in blanks with -99.0 (the software I use recognizes -99.0 as a numeric missing) and X (the software I use recognizes X as text missing) if text.  I searched and only saw manual way of stating what all the column names are.  This would work repeatedly if the column names never changed but from project to project, I won't always have the same columns nor column names.  Trying to automate this.  Here's a small example:

| ID | Project | From | To | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 0 | 10 | 15 | 0.578 |
| 1 | AAA | 10 | 20 | 7.6 |  |
| 2 |  | 0 | 100 | 14 | 0.777 |
| 2 |  | 100 | 200 | 6.5 |  |
| 1 | ABA | 0 | 5 | 22.7 | 0.431 |
| 1 | BBB | 15 | 20 | 0.8 | 17.4 |
| 2 |  | 0 | 10 |  | 1.200 |
| 2 | BBB | 10 | 20 | 6.9 | 200.8 |

I know I can just do this but it only does numeric:

```
result.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Also I could try this but put -99.0:

```
dataframe[list_of_columns].replace(r'\s+', 0, regex=True)
```

But then that is very manual and I want this to be automated since I have alot of projects and looking to save time and it only does numeric, not text columns.

There's this one I found but I can't convert text blanks to "X".  I assume it would be something similar to this where I save the list_of_columns then have a for loop?

def recode_empty_cells(dataframe, list_of_columns):

```
for column in list_of_columns:
  dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
  dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].fillna(0)

return dataframe
```

In the end I want it to look like this:

| ID | Project | From | To | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 0 | 10 | 15 | 0.578 |
| 1 | AAA | 10 | 20 | 7.6 | -99.0 |
| 2 | X | 0 | 100 | 14 | 0.777 |
| 2 | X | 100 | 200 | 6.5 | -99.0 |
| 1 | ABA | 0 | 5 | 22.7 | 0.431 |
| 1 | BBB | 15 | 20 | 0.8 | 17.4 |
| 2 | X | 0 | 10 | -99.0 | 1.200 |
| 2 | BBB | 10 | 20 | 6.9 | 200.8 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends. The data as you've shown (with blanks in the number coulmns) would technically not have a numeric dtype if that's how it's stored in pandas (the missing value for numeric is `NaN`, if it's `''` the column **must** be object). But if you use pandas I/O to infer the dtype (as it will fill this table with the correct `NaN` then you can do what you'd like based on `dtypes`

Comment: @ALollz So if I had it correctly formatted, how could I automate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your columns have the correct `dtypes` then you can use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html). Select the numeric types and fill with `-99` and then exclude the numeric types and fill with `X`. Then join the results back and reindex (if you care about column ordering).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = (pd.concat([df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).fillna(-99),
                 df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).fillna('X')], axis=1)
        .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
```

---

```
   ID Project  From   To  Value1   Value2
0   1     AAA     0   10    15.0    0.578
1   1     AAA    10   20     7.6  -99.000
2   2       X     0  100    14.0    0.777
3   2       X   100  200     6.5  -99.000
4   1     ABA     0    5    22.7    0.431
5   1     BBB    15   20     0.8   17.400
6   2       X     0   10   -99.0    1.200
7   2     BBB    10   20     6.9  200.800
```

---

Another valid option is to use `select_dtypes` to get the columns, then just manually fill. Since we only care about the column labels, and a column always has a single `dtype`, we can just use `.head(1)`. It turns out that since `df.select_dtypes` returns a slice of the DataFrame it becomes slow for larger DataFrames, but we only need one row for this.

```
num_cols = df.head(1).select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns
oth_cols = df.head(1).select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns

df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].fillna(-99)
df[oth_cols] = df[oth_cols].fillna('X')
```